# mysql retrieving newest entry between set integers

Tags: php, mysql

Okay the title may not justify what I'm trying to do here but dont know my problem well enough to explain it perfectly.

What i'm trying to do:

I need to retrieve rows from a MySQL data base where response = 8 or 9 but display the newest entry if there are multiple matches. Let say I have 6 rows and 1 rows have response = 8 and 2 row where response = 9 I want to retrieve the newest entry based on row id.

example:

row1 id=12 user_id = 15 response = 8

row2 id=11 user_id = 15 response = 9

row3 id=10 user_id = 15 response = 1

row4 id=09 user_id = 15 response = 9

row5 id=08 user_id = 15 response = 4

row6 id=07 user_id = 15 response = 5

I want to retrieve row1 since it's the newest entry where response = 8 or 9

I tried but failed:

`SELECT a.id, MAX(a.response) FROM user a WHERE a.user_id = $userID AND a.response IN (8,9) GROUP BY a.user_id`

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT u.id, u.user_id, u.response
FROM user u
WHERE u.id in 
(
 SELECT max(id) FROM user WHERE user_id = $userID  and response IN (8,9)
) ;




ID  USER_ID RESPONSE
12  15  8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.id, MAX(a.response) -- Your columns
FROM user a -- Table
WHERE a.user_id = $userID -- your ESCAPED parameters (see mysql prepared stmts)
AND a.response IN (8,9)
GROUP BY a.response
ORDER BY a.id DESC -- the greater the ID, the 'newer'
LIMIT 1 -- just get one record
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I have understood your question and you want the newest row (i.e. highest value in `id` column) for the specified user but only where the response is 8 or 9, try

```
SELECT id 
FROM user 
WHERE user_id = $userID 
  AND response IN (8,9)
ORDER BY id DESC
```